# What would be the right site for this question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I tried it on webapps but it wasn't well-received there. I realize now that it's intended for power *users* of webapps, so not appropriate.

To me, it almost doesn't belong on Stack Overflow itself because there (probably) isn't a concrete answer. If there was, I suspect I would have found it after a long time I spent on web searches before asking.

Any tips would be appreciated

[Why is the client time zone (not just offset) not available in the browser? [Closed]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72759/why-is-the-client-time-zone-not-just-offset-not-available-in-the-browser)

Editors note: The referred question was deleted by Community user as RemovedAbandonedClosed, below is the body:

> We are often interested in obtaining the client's time zone (ex:
>   America/Los_Angeles), for obvious reasons. Unfortunately, this isn't
>   directly available within the browser. Instead, we have to rely on
>   asking the user, or attempting to detect it - with reasonable accuracy
>   - using some Javascript that examines various date offsets (ex: jstz as described here).
>
> My questions is, why not? Obviously the offset is available, which is
>   based on the time zone. But why not the time zone itself? It would
>   save the headache of having to use hacks to determine it, and of
>   course one could always use other means to determine it with more
>   confidence (ex: asking the client). Are there security implications,
>   or a lack of interest in creating a standard solution, or something
>   else I might be missing?

Comment: To poke holes:  what browser are you talking about?  We are all acutely aware that every browser does different things in regards to its supported functions...

Comment: Very true.  This answer hints at some browser-specific support but doesn't mention any specifics.  I suspect if any did, then browser-unification tools like jQuery would support it.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18252251/375670

Comment: This _looks like_ a question for Super User, but I strongly suspect the answer to it is "[because time zones aren't consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)".

Comment: I'd upvote your question but I don't know about others. @KevinBrown Where in the page does it say that?

Comment: I don't think the inconsistency of time zone definitions, itself, is relevant to my question.  The point is there is a setting somewhere in the operating system for time zone, which for all practical purposes is a string (however weird or inconsistent that string value), and it's exposed in a half-working way through the browser.  Why not just let the browser have the string value?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't evaluate the question anymore.

Comment: @rene: Yes, that seems fair.

Comment: Similar, if not duplicate (yes, asked after this one, but it has many more votes than this): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/215552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid non of the sites within the Stack Exchange Network will be a good fit for the question in its current state.

Although it seems nicely disguised as a technical question the answers will be mostly opinion based and/or hearsay unless the user that answers the question was present at the design meeting JavaScript and/or the standards body that now governs its development.

It seems however a reasonable question, if asked well (and assuming it isn't a duplicate). So why wouldn't you reword this and explain the difficulties you have to detect the timezone. You can show some of the workarounds you have in place and then demonstrate with a small [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that correct detection fails. Your can then ask if there is solution to this problem.

The answers might confirm what you already concluded: the specifications lack any support so you're on your own, or someone has a nice library that covers all corner-cases, or you overlooked a simple solution. In the extra ordinary case you'll get background on the reasons why it was designed this way, anecdotal   or not.

Comment: Just for posterity, it seems that this is now available via ECMAScript internationalization features, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/375670

`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: @JeffEvans well, that was about time it got a spec and an implementation...