# Is it bad to ask a question that seeks an explanation for observed behavior?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I asked [Why is my subclass required to override with default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197740/why-is-my-subclass-required-to-override-with-default-parameters) It is about a compiler error, which I know how to fix. My question was about *why* it was a compiler error.

It received mixed votes. Why is this a controversial question, warranting equal up and down votes? (I use the term "controversial" very loosely.)  Is it because I am asking for an explanation, opposed to a black-and-white answer?

Comment: I believe that as long as it's not a rhetorical question, then asking in order to have a deeper understanding of a topic is not a problem (But I might be wrong)

Comment: It seems like a fine question to me. Some people probably just didn't understand what you were asking. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio (PS: Please don't leave "Why the downvote?" comments under posts on the main site. They aren't seen by the people you want them to be seen by, and they just add clutter.)

Comment: Standard explanation for downvotes is lack of *demonstrated* effort - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+override+default+value+virtual ... gives decent amount of discussions which include links to spec. Adding link to part of C# specification that you don't understand would significantly improve the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I searched that search, in Bing actually, prior to asking my question.  None of those top results answered my question, or I misunderstood the answer if it was there.

Comment: @Evorlor You could just search for the compiler error you were getting, and that explains it easily enough.

Comment: @Servy I understand the compiler error.  That was not the issue.  I wanted to know why it was a compiler error.

Comment: He isn't claiming you didn't search ... lack of **demonstrated** effort ... (emphasis is mine). At least add what material you looked at and why it didn't answer your question.

Comment: @rene You are probably right.  I usually go for concise questions, and leave out information irrelevant to the question itself.  But in this case, it appears I should have been more clear on the research I had done before hand.

Comment: @Evorlor If you understand the compiler error then why wouldn't you understand why it's a compiler error?  And regardless, if you want to know more about that compiler error, like why it exists, again, just do a search on it, there's lots of info out there on it.

Comment: @Servy Assuming you read the question, and that is still unclear, then my question is deserving of the downvotes.  My question was unclear.  (Which answers this meta-question.)  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comments to this question, it appears the downvotes came because my question was unclear.  I will try to be more thorough in the future.  Thank you all very much in helping me to ask better questions.