# Are questions about design decisions made by third parties on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I've observed a number of questions where it could be argued that the topic being asked about is not really a programming question but rather an inquiry into why a programming language or instruction set was designed in a particular way. Some examples:

[Why is xor'ing DS not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640036/why-is-xoring-ds-not-allowed)

[Why don't x86 16-bit addressing modes have a scale factor, while the 32-bit version has it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657904/why-dont-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes-have-a-scale-factor-while-the-32-bit-vers)

[Why not exist syntax which execute some operation multiple times without define a counter in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654319/why-not-exist-syntax-which-execute-some-operation-multiple-times-without-define#comment97997385_55654319)

I expressed my opinion about this type of question in my answer on the first link; namely, that it is not on topic on Stack Overflow and that it is extremely difficult to give a correct answer unless you are one of the designers of the technology being asked about - the best you can do is speculate in many cases.

So, are questions of this sort on topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio

Comment: I'd say that even if such a question manages to be on-topic, it is still not recommended to ask such a question. One thing is an absolute given: it will receive downvotes, it will receive close votes. Just for the very nature of the question which smells off-topic and poorly researched. If it will receive less downvotes than upvotes or if it will not receive enough close votes to actually be closed... you just don't know.