# Reopen an old but still-relevant MySQL question with high-quality answers?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

[Is MySQL breaking the standard by allowing selecting columns that are not part of the group by clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7594865) was closed 9 years ago or so for being ["not constructive"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7594865/timeline).

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

It is a common question about MySQL's implementation of `GROUP BY`, and has some of the most useful expert answers I have seen on the topic. The answers are from experts, and are well-supported by facts and references. One of the close-voters even added a somewhat useful answer.

The question and answers have been well-received judging by the accumulated votes.

Can it be reopened? I lack the reputation score necessary to cast a reopen vote on this site in the network.

---

I understand that the modern "opinion-based" close reason could apply these days. That said, we close questions because they create problems, or don't result in content that helps the goal of SO — to create a library of great Q & A — not by a blind application of rigid rules for their own sake.

The close votes were probably warranted at the time they were cast. My contention is that none of the *potential* undesirable outcomes were encountered in this case. This is a fine example of a long-term useful Q & A that ought to be reopened.

I am hoping that subject-matter experts will vote to reopen this question.

Leaving this valuable Q & A closed detracts from its legitimacy. This might dissuade people from clicking through from a search engine or on-site search results, or demotivate people from curating that page as it deserves. Surely some people include `closed:no` in site search e.g. when looking for duplicate targets. Over time, it might become necessary to add a new answer as well.

---

Thank you all for your considered feedback, the question has now been **successfully reopened**.

Comment: It looks like an **opinion based** question as noted by the close reason (comments can still be added): *As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [visit the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) for guidance.*

Comment: Why does it need to be reopened?  It won't be deleted by the roomba, and it has no delete votes against it, so the answers aren't going anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the *question itself*, regardless of the answers, should be reopened. See [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/11682469) Why does it need to be reopened? The question and its answers are still visible. The reason it didn't lead to problems could be that it was closed 9 years ago.

Comment: What is missing is an explanation on why or how that question adheres to SO standards.

Comment: @JeanneDark it didn't. But luckily for us the answers provided enough material to retrofit the question to be acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has now been reopened thanks to the three expert users involved.

We have made [a copy of the question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/294989) for [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and will maintain it from there.

That way less will be lost if the question is closed again here, or even deleted eventually.

Answer (score 2):

The question still reads as an opinion-based question. We can't know with total authority why MySQL devs decided to do something (not even if the devs themselves answer it). So, I edited the question to ask "Is MySQL breaking the standard, and if so how and what is the practical result?" which is what the top answer actually answers.

This is the first step towards reopening any question: solve the issues that it has. The best way to do that is via editing.

Comment: @PaulWhite to ask "why" something is done, you should first establish if it's done, that's what the top answer does: it tells you that the quote is at least obsolete. So, MySQL isn't doing what the quote says it shouldn't do, it's doing something else. The way you propose explicitly says that MySQL is wrong, which has its problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an **opinion-based** question as noted by the close reason (comments can still be added):

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [visit the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) for guidance.

Regarding the question posed:

> Can it [question] be reopened?

**Yes!**

> Users with 3,000 reputation can cast up to 50 reopen votes per day. When a question reaches 3 reopen votes, it is no longer closed, and new answers may be submitted. You may only vote to close or reopen a question once. To cast a reopen vote, click the "reopen" link beneath the question. Moderators may close or reopen any question with a single vote.

Source: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

There is currently 1 vote to reopen, so 2 more and it would be open. In any case, comments can be added to the current question and answers.

You could also post the link on the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) with the tag [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls) to notify fellow users.