# My question about "why javax.sql was not re-designed" was closed with no feedback

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

My question has recently been closed due to *breaking the community guidelines*.

Question: [Unused interfaces in javax.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393074/unused-interfaces-in-javax-sql)

Nobody explained to me how the question was in violation with the site's guidelines.

If it were possible to improve, I'd expect a comment or two about that.

Nobody suggested that I post the question on a different site.

I have responded to all comments as best as I could.

I have invested a lot of effort into my question so this is somewhat frustrating.

Comment: The close message says *This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).*

Comment: @RobertLongson That's just a broad default reason. It clearly doesn't help this author.

Comment: @Scratte The OP therefore needs to explain why this isn't useful feedback rather than claiming there's no feedback at all.

Comment: *why haven't the Java designers rethought the design of this package?"*. This is probably why it was closed

Comment: @RoberLongson I may be willing to admit that my question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. But surely, there must be a place for me to ask such a question. This is what I missed when my question got closed.

Comment: This seems to be your question *"Due to the fact that a large part of the APIs provided in package javax.sql are effectively unused, why haven't the Java designers rethought the design of this package?"* which isn't really answerable except for some Java API designers. While it is related to programming, it doesn't seem to be "a specific programming problem" nor a "a practical, answerable problem". See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Asking historical questions and "why language/framework does/doesn't implement X" is generally off-topic on SO... as well as asking "where else to ask outside of SE" is off-topic on Meta.  To make your particular one somewhat entertaining you should explain why you are so sure that "Java designers {haven't} rethought the design of this package" (in most cases changing interface of existing product is ... impossible)

Comment: _"there must be a place"_ - maybe, but SO isn't a clearinghouse for the rest of the internet. Your question can be migrated if it's a clear fit for one of the target sites, but in this case I don't think there is one within the network.

Comment: see also: [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601)

Comment: "But surely, there must be a place for me to ask such a question." Maybe there is, but just as the question is not in the scope of Stack Overflow, nor is finding somewhere that *is* in scope.

Comment: *"I have invested a lot of effort into my question"* - not enough to include PostgreSQL and Oracle drivers which would probably paint quite a different picture. Time spent is not exactly the same as effort made, you did limit yourself to a few easy targets only. Regardless, this is pretty much the prototype question which goes absolutely nowhere on Stack Overflow but will probably be welcomed with open arms on Reddit; people will be jumping at the possibility to share their guesswork.

Answer (score 14):

The closure banner tells you the reason and links you to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)...

[image]

Your question boils down to *"why haven't the Java designers rethought the design of this package?"*

That's something only those specific designers can answer. That's not within the scope of SO.