# Why were some of my questions badly received? Should some of them be deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, quality-improvement

Some of my questions were negatively received.

- [Why Data.Text.Lazy is needed? Can't be strict chuncks of lazy structure made by a compiler optimilizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207896/haskell-ghc-why-data-text-lazy-is-needed/)
- [Haskell Megaparsec Multiprocessing Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71131646/haskell-megaparsec-multiprocessing-error-handling) (deleted)
- [Linux Cryptsetup UUID problem in initramfs while mounting Btrfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821611/linux-cryptsetup-uuid-problem-in-initramfs-while-mounting-btrfs) (migrated to Unix & Linux)

I want to learn how to make my questions better and which questions shouldn't be even asked.

One of these question was found to be nonsense, but it was asked in good faith. Should it be deleted?

Comment: Can't really comment on the Haskell questions, but the third one is not about programming.

Comment: The second one was caused by a typo? Why haven't you deleted it yet, or at least self-answered it? Also, please don't tag your questions titles. There are already question tags, no need to duplicate them in the title.

Comment: The first question has two close votes for "Opinion Based". It is possible that your "Why" question is answered by "Because the developers of the language did so", which enters [this area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio).

Comment: @Tom The second one was caused by wrong consideration about the problem. I wasn't sure whether to delete it. But when I think about it now, it should be deleted.

Comment: @yivi The third was about me trying to fix my script generating initramfs. So it is a little bit of programming. Should it be moved to other website then? Authors of cryptsetup answerd me and the answer is linked to comment, so it is little useful for future visitor.

Comment: The last question should certainly not have been asked on [so]. Perhaps [unix.se] would have been a better choice. Asking on the wrong community is often a reason for downvotes.

Comment: @Larnu You probably meant the third. How should I choose between Unix & Linux, Super User, Server Fault and Stack Overflow, when the question is connected to every website a little bit?

Comment: The third question is the last question, @PřemyslŠťastný ? As for the latter, read the site's [tour] and use the one that is most suited. There are certainly overlaps between communities, some more so than others, but they all very informative on what is (and isn't) on topic.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator What should be done with the first question? Close? Delete? Edit (somehow)?

Comment: Good attitude by the way. You essentially asked "what can be improved?", the product of a neutral mind. I see someone asking that in comments, I don't hesitate to provide a response if I feel capable to do so. A lot of people ask "what is wrong!?" though, the product of a mind looking for someone to dislike and blame. That should give a hint as to why this kind of feedback is not so forthcoming on the main site, unfortunately.

Comment: the comments usually point to the right way, opion based questions, questions without a mre are usually badly received and yours are a good example how question shouldn't be asked

Comment: @nbk Yes. I know it...the original question should be, whether is it possible to do it theoretically. Not why it isn't implemented. But what should I do with such a question, when there are lots of comments and one answer related to the original question and might be useful for future visitor?

Comment: Edit your question to comply with the comments, they are basically not that high downvoted,  that you can't recover,

Comment: Just to be sure it's stated very loudly and obviously - deleting your questions isn't going to "help" your score on how well your questions are received.  If any deleted questions are negative they'll still count towards a question ban.  But I do want to laud you on your mindset here - looking to improve your questions and understand what to do on how to make them better is a genuine breath of fresh air.

Comment: @Makoto I know that. Fortunately, I am far from question ban...I have a lot of well received questions. Only some of them are garbage by the opinion of the community and I am trying to find out why.

Comment: I have edited https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207896/why-data-text-lazy-is-needed-cant-be-strict-chuncks-of-lazy-structure-made-by. Is it okey now please? @nbk

Comment: @E_net4thecurator Is the first question better now please?

Comment: Leave that to the subject matter experts to decide. I just threw in a hypothesis based on how the question was phrased, but I don't know Haskell enough to say more.

Comment: For the first question, a spell checker would easily have caught "[generaly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/generally#Adverb)" (though for some unknown reason not *"[optimilizer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/optimiser#Noun)"* in the title (it ***is*** squiggled if in the body) - at least for the spell checker in Firefox). See also *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/)*. Meta information, like explicit addressing (*"Do you know any other way"*), does not belong in the post itself. This is not a forum.

Comment: [Word order for questions in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s) (titles are not different in this regard). Yesterday's question had this problem. That wasn't a problem at all for older questions. Why was there a regression?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you for your warning about my grammar. It was years since my last English exam, so I successfully forget some of rules of the language. I should refresh them and be more careful about them.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný - There are free tools like Grammarly.  However, in order for them to be helpful, you have to be somewhere in the ballpark.

Comment: Have you looked over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation

Comment: @treedust I have read it few years ago. It looks like it improved since then. Thanks for a hint. :-)

Comment: @Gimby Personally I don't find "what is wrong" that different from "what can I improve" as they are just two ways to arrive at the same information. What is problematic is when instead the reaction is something like "why does Stack Overflow suck" or "why did these moderators close my clearly fine question", etc.

Comment: @TylerH The crucial difference is punctuation. "What is wrong?" is probably neutral, but "What is wrong?!" (as in Gimby's comment) already suggests aggression and makes me not want to help that person. And your examples are on the far end of the scale for bad comments.

Comment: I was somewhat disheartened to stumble upon [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253627/python-haskell-ffi-how-to-elegantly-represent-infinite-haskell-recursive-dat) and realise it belongs to the same user as this meta. Leaving out all the fluff of obsessive thinking and such, it's just "In Python, how to represent infinite datastructure without non-constructor functions using Haskell FFI"? That's it. No examples, no use-case, no template, just a vague request that it should be "easy" and "elegant". Asking people to do *all* the work isn't going to be well received...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's theoretical question. Any example, any usecase would make it more concrete and won't range the whole field of what is it about. - I was writting there a usecase about eg. caching, but the answer would be then about caching, not about the abstract problem itself. So I deleted it.

Comment: You might want to take another look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page. Questions should be about *specific* / *practical* problems; questions that require answers that span the whole field at once are generally not appropriate.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný -I am not sure what you mean by "I was writing", that implies, you were writing a paper or some form of formal writing. If that is the case, that is well beyond the purpose of Stack Overflow, and your question would be out of scope. Your experience at Stack Overflow, will be positive if you follow a simple principle, you must tell us what you have tried and the reason you suspect it's not working. In order to do that you can provide us your current output and tell us why that output isn't correct. Ultimately, asking for elegant solutions, is asking for a discussion on the topic

Comment: It also does not help, that you reverse [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71253627/revisions), that improve your question.

Comment: @SecurityHound The edits was destroying the content of the question. Please join us here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242370/discussion-between-tylerh-and-premysl-sastny

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange works is **it's a user-managed community.**  So if you have enough votes to your name, you can review the questions asked and take actions such as editing them, up/down voting them, etc. usually before anyone else gets to the questions, because your reputation is higher.  That means that certain people will be okay with questions phrased a certain way, and some won't be okay with the same format...  There are humans reading your questions, and they will be human.

Sometimes, you think your question is clear, and the answer you are looking for is also clear, but because of how you arranged your question, other readers don't think so.  **The key is to try to make your question very specific, with a small example of the issue you are facing that is reproducible, with a clear description of the exact problem you are trying to remedy.  This will make responses to your question generally more relevant.**

I have had plenty of situations where formulating the question is rather difficult, especially when working with new libraries where I am not familiar with the inner-workings.  Some users of the forum expect me to know more than I actually do, but documentation is lacking or the library is rather esoteric.  Now this is advice I don't take myself at times, but I strongly suggest it...
**If someone suggests that you edit your question because it isn't clear, take a read over it again and ensure that your question is well defined.  That is easier said than done in some cases, but just give it your best shot.  Something like: I have a question that has forum posts reference 1, reference 2 which do not apply to my specific situation because of the difference XYZ.  So I am asking this question to gather insight into how to solve this specific problem.  Usually, showing effort before posting will make people more willing to help you, and avoid getting downvotes.**

All of this is just my opinion gathered from experiences using the forums.  The clearer I state the question, the better the answers I receive.  If I read over the question and can't derive exactly what my question is, well, how will anyone else?  As for your question about deleting posts that are not receiving good responses, that's all up to you.  I imagine you had a question you were trying to get an answer to, so it would likely be better to re-read it and clarify the question, if you haven't received an adequate answer to date.

Now I read over your active questions, and the answers aren't really that informative, and most of the discussion is in the comments.  As mentioned above, you want to ask very specific questions or you'll just get generic answers. Sometimes it's better to reformulate your question and post a new one than to rely on an old one that hasn't had a good response.  The older questions can sometimes slip through the cracks and not get any attention.

Comment: *usually before anyone else gets to the questions, because your reputation is higher* – what do you mean by that? As far as I know, questions are visible to everyone at the same time, not prioritized for users with higher reputation.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Questions by users below a certain reputation threshold, are automatically put into queue, while the question has been submitted and anyone can view it during that review period active reviewers are active and take action quickly.

Answer (score 6):

In general, people upvote questions they find interesting and downvote questions they dislike. These aren't opposing qualities: in most cases people find questions simply uninteresting but doesn't necessarily dislike it and they move on without voting.

In *[Why is Data.Text.Lazy needed? Couldn't strict chunks of a lazy structure be made by a compiler optimizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207896/haskell-ghc-why-data-text-lazy-is-needed/)*, the primary problem I can see is that it's extremely vague. What exact optimization are you speaking of? To what extent do you understand that optimization? Do you understand the constraints on both types? Do you know the trade-off of the optimization? Short of writing a book on the topic, there is no way to write a comprehensive answer.

That is a problem. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, with self-contained and well-scoped questions and answers. Such an open-ended question isn't a good fit. That is why people disliked it.

But you may argue: "that's the point of asking, I don't know!" And that's the heart of the problem. Asking a good question requires you to know enough to express what exactly you don't understand. Asking a good question typically involves researching as far as you can so you could pinpoint where you are stuck on.

As for deletion, I don't think it needs to be. There is already an answer, and deleting your question will also remove it.

Comment: "In general, people upvote questions they find interesting and downvote questions they dislike" - I sincerely hope that this is not the general case, because then in general it is done wrong. Usefulness (and actual quality) is the key factor for quality voting. Interest is what draws you to look at a question, but after that it stops being a factor.

Comment: @Gimby There's quite a bit of evidence that posts do simply get upvoted out of interest quite often.