# Why was my question downvoted and closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [What optimisations have Microsoft done to VS Code/Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221449/what-optimisations-have-microsoft-done-to-vs-code-electron)

My post got voted down, closed, and deleted without anyone commenting to explain why they thought it was "opinion-based".

I don't see why it would lead to "opinions rather than facts and citations". Even before the edit, I didn't see much of a "what's your opinion on this" to it.

Can someone help me understand what about my post would incite opinions?

For users below 10k, here's the now deleted question:

> ### What optimisations have Microsoft done to VS Code/Electron?
>
> I've seen several instances where people claim that Microsoft optimised Electron (or at the very least, Electron Apps), but I can't seem to find any information that verifies this claim.
>
> As examples of such claims, [here's a post from Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17310870), and [here's a reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/q6q3t2/comment/hgepc5f/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), and [another reddit comment from that same thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/q6q3t2/comment/hggxn6l/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).
>
> Is the claim misinformation? Are there any specific optimisations that Microsoft employ for improving VS Code?
>
> I've read that Microsoft contribute performance improvements upstream to Chromium, which filters its way down to Electron. However, I've not managed to find information to back that claim either.
>
> What I'm looking for is evidence/citations of what Microsoft do to make VS Code appear to others as having an edge over other electron-based apps.
>
> [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance)[visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)[electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron)

Comment: Potentially related (idk, I can't see the deleted post): [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/3270037)

Comment: Thanks @yivi for the edit. It slipped my mind that people can't see deleted content

Comment: Your main site question looks like one that would generate extensive discussion and debate.

Comment: I would have voted it as off-topic due to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial *or other off-site resource*", but I can see a case for opinion: "to make VS Code *appear to others* as" completely depends on the personal preference and impression of "others". It's also somewhat vague what one could consider "specific optimisations that Microsoft employ". Either way, the question largely depends on interpretation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That comment is better as an answer. It's the perfect answer in fact. Thank you so much for not being pedantic for the sake of it, or just repeating words that I can already find on the site that have clearly not been helpful

Comment: @JamesYeoman You're probably right, I've taken some time to expand it to a proper answer.

Comment: Long story short, Stack Overflow is intended for programming problems. This is more of a curiosity thing on your part. From the perspective of a Q&A repository, that falls in the "not useful" category. Hence: downvotes. Nobody benefits from knowing that Microsoft applied optimisations to Electron or not, the only thing that matters is if Electron fits your needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the question effectively is asking for "facts or citations", the topic of *what* these should cover is a matter of interpretation – i.e. opinion.

To single out the two main criteria that an answer would likely have to cover:

> Are there any specific optimisations that Microsoft employ for improving VS Code?

I know this might seem specific, but it is actually rather vague. Are these only optimisations that Microsoft uses and absolutely no one else? Are these only optimisations that "specifically" stand out, by whatever criteria? Are these any optimisations that Microsoft uses?

Even if one were to decide on some interpretation, it would likely still result in a huge listing – so answerers would have to pick *some* subset at a whim.

> What I'm looking for is evidence/citations of what Microsoft do to make VS Code **appear to others** as having an edge over other electron-based apps.

Emphasis mine; how things appear to others is ultimately a matter of those others' opinion and preference. There is no single authoritative "other" whose opinion might be clearly and officially documented, either.

This makes it kind of "double opinionated": Answers would have to follow their opinion on whose others opinion is relevant.

---

For what it's worth, even eliminating the aspect of opinion would likely not make the question on-topic.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial **or other off-site resource** are off-topic […]
> -- Help Center: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 9):

Your post is conjecture at best and it argues against itself right off the bat.

You didn't post a question, you posted a "sate my curiosity because I don't know how" post.

> I've seen several instances where people claim that Microsoft optimised Electron (or at the very least, Electron Apps), but I can't seem to find any information that verifies this claim.

Well, what's stopping you from reading the source code? https://github.com/electron/electron

MS Teams is apparently built on electronjs so I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft contributed to the opensource project https://www.electronjs.org/apps/microsoft-teams

Here's an extensive list of apps built using electronjs, https://www.electronjs.org/apps. Why did you fail to ask whether any of the other companies made optimizations to electronjs?

---

Whether or not "opinion-based" is the right close reason? Meh.

The [appropriate close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252592/2191572) was taken away years ago.

Comment: Granted, I should have included my attempts at finding answers, like search terms. But I at least put effort in, cited places that make the assertion, mentioned that I had difficulty verifying the claim, and what I wanted to get out of the question (citations, and explanations). If I were familiar with Electron's codebase, then your suggestion would have been understandable.

The salt in the wound is that a question like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207477/what-does-this-header-mean-in-c has 3 answers while showing no attempt at prior research.

Comment: Stack Overflow experiences 10 questions per minute so if you could help out and downvote these salt-wound posts instead of adding to the moderation burden then that would be great. Yes, that question is minimal and doesn't show much  effort, it **is** objectively answerable. Your post was an invitation for discussion and you would presumably end up with 20 comments per answer trying to argue one way or another. The only possible objective answer is for you to read the code, comments, and pull/merge requests, or for an MS employee to personally write an answer.

Comment: @JamesYeoman - If you have found a question with no attempt to research then you should downvote the question.  Sounds like you now understand why your question was closed though.  Followed my own advice.  Thanks for bringing a poorly researched question to our attention. I also downvoted an answer with a sarcastic remark.

Comment: Yeah you're right. In light of MisterMiyagi's answer, this answer doesn't come across as pedantic and hostile as it originally came across to me. All I wanted was to know why it was opinion-based because I couldn't see why. Do you have any suggestions for how I can avoid causing situations like this in the future? Seeing how unproductive this whole ordeal was, I don't want to cause it again