# Is this question about Amazon S3 on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I'd like some help determining whether a question I have about S3 object reindexing is on topic.

The [Amazon S3 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3) warns that support, functionality and configuration questions are off-topic. However, I believe my question boils down to: what is the runtime complexity for reindexing the unknown-to-me data structure underlying S3, which *seems* on topic.

Here is the content of the proposed question:

> It seems you cannot rename an object on S3.  An endless amount of
> answers here on SO indicate that the best you can do is copy the
> object, then delete the old one.
>
> See various related questions:
>
> - [How to rename objects boto3 S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492462/how-to-rename-objects-boto3-s3?noredirect=1&lq=1)
> - [Boto3/S3: Renaming an object using copy_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501995/boto3-s3-renaming-an-object-using-copy-object)
> - [How to rename files and folder in Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3)
> - [How to rename AWS S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41511034/1456253)
>
> According to these questions, this is true across various language
> APIs, including the AWS command line tools (the mv command warns that
> it just copies), and the online GUI (the rename action copies as
> well).
>
> However, I have not found a clear *technical* reason for why this is
> the case. There are many key value data structures which allow
> reindexing.
>
> In order to keep things on topic, here are some possible types of
> answers which I'll make up:
>
> 1. The S3 system is backed by a ??? distributed block data structure,
>    reindexing can't be atomic due to its decentralized nature, and
>    multiple reindex commands even to all servers might put the system
>    in a never ending cycle of reindexing or could violate data
>    integrity. Aka the structure makes it **impossible**.
> 2. The S3 system is backed by a ??? distributed block data structure, reindexing is theoretically possible, but only achieved by the
>    following process which is a O(n^3) nightmare, making it
>    **prohibitively expensive** to perform.
> 3. This restriction has nothing to do with S3's technical implementation, which does allow reindexing, and **AWS simply decided
>    not to expose this functionality**.
> 4. Also acceptable: The S3 system is an absolute blackbox and AWS doesn't allow for its internal implementation to be known. **The
>    question cannot be answered with the information we have**.

Comment: This probably amounts to the same reasons why [questions about language specifications or design decisions are closed as opinion based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio).

Comment: #1 is likely the truth, since we do know [S3 buckets are partitioned](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/).  That said, the exact technical details aren't published and likely the only people that have a concrete answer are behind NDAs.  Even if it was known, it's really an implementation detail, all we can say is S3 doesn't have a Rename API.

Comment: I wouldn't post a question which only implies a question though. Actually ask the question. Don't make it so people have to think about what you are actually asking, as you will face very rich imaginations.

Answer (score 9):

Eh... I would say that it's *not* on-topic.

The question boiled down to its essence is, "What technical evidence does S3 provide for not choosing to allow someone to rename an object?"  The answer only lives with S3 engineers and architects.

To be blunt though, a rename really *is* just a copy operation of an existing object (with new name) and a delete operation.  A "rename" operation is just syntactic sugar over those two steps.

Comment: I can accept the first part. However, technically, I imagine the system eventually boils down to flat files supported by some metadata structure. 

Imagine naively a hashmap holding references to files. There's no reason I have to move the data in order to reindex it in the metadata structure.

Comment: @code11:  The reason is "because AWS said so".  Technically - as in technologically - you have a point, but from an objective answer perspective, "AWS said no", so that's what we're going to have to go off of.

Comment: Would the question be better phrased as asking what datastructure underlies S3?

Comment: @code11:  No, since it suffers from the same injury - **only S3 engineers and architects could answer the question** in a practical sense, and it doesn't really *change* the fact that you are prohibited from doing so today.

Comment: Hmm. I believe that means its off topic for any SE site. I know AWS has published a number of white papers about their technology, but I wasn't able to find one on this explicitly. Unfortunate. I think people would be interested in the answer if AWS ever wants to give us a peek behind the curtain.