# My "Why..." question was closed for being opinion-based

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, opinion-based

Yesterday, I asked [Why aren't traits Sized by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062589/why-arent-traits-sized-by-default) which was closed for potentially being opinion based.
I didn't agree, so I voted to reopen it.
Upon reopening, it got a well-received answer, which contained a citation to the documentation of `Sized`.
I just saw that it was closed again for the same reason, and this time, I can't vote to reopen it.

Given that the question *does* seem like it's opinion-based (but has an objective answer), should I have phrased it differently?

Comment: I'd argue the closure is incorrect, but also the wording of the question is such that it certainly looks like it'd be primary opinion based... it's just in this case the docs actually provide the answer rather than it being something for everyone to just speculate on.

Comment: "Why ..." questions are basically asking for the motivation behind the decision.  Any answers will almost always be someone's best guess (their opinion).

Comment: I voted to close it as opinion because the SME who answered it said this after quoting the docs said, regarding the _actual_ question you asked, "*As for why Sized is the default on everything else (functions, structs, enums, types, etc,) **requires more guesswork***" (bold emphasis mine). If an SME says it's a matter of guesswork, then it's not really going to be objectively answerable.

Comment: @TylerH: *As for why Sized is the default on everything else (functions, structs, enums, types, etc,)* was never asked in the question though. The only mentioning of function sizes is in the sentence *", but why isn't Sized the default like it is for functions?"*, which is different to why are functions sized.

Comment: In general, questions asking 'why is language feature `x` designed in `y` way is a matter of opinion: the answer is usually "because the authors of the feature decided so". Related: [Is asking why on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: Why questions may sometimes ask for motivation. In this case, the answer isn't at all opinion based because the reason is a technical one, not an arbitrary decision.

Comment: @BDL You're right, I missed that the answerer was addressing a different question there, as that's an unusual thing for an answerer to do. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Since the creation of [langdev.se], sometimes I wonder if such a question is more appropriate there or not. (Note: I'm not a regular there, so I don't know the current policy)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Should I have avoided beginning my question with "Why"? Could it have been made more clear that it was seeking a technical explanation?

Comment: Sometimes the motivation is documented on the minutes of the Standardization body's meetings, sometimes it's documented in a technical report or in a book like *The Design and Evolution of C++*, and sometimes the reasoning [can be read or inferred from the Standard document itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77048368/4581301). Most of the time there is no authoritative answer, though. Just educated guesses.

Comment: Even if the answer is technical, it will usually be difficult for the OP to tell which answer is actually correct so it can be accepted; the best you can do is judge the "most plausible" explanation. The exception is when there's a Rationale document somewhere that explains the reason.

Comment: @AndrewT. Cody has thoughts on that (that PLDI is bad for the health of SO by sucking away interesting questions potentially like the one being discussed here). I think why questions about how/why language designers make certain decisions are valuable and can be constructive as long as they insist that citations be given instead of guesses.

Comment: I don't think *why* questions are necessarily opinion-based, but voted to close as *'Needs details or clarity'* because it was not clear what the specific problem was.

Comment: *"should I have phrased it differently?"* - obviously. You *shouldn't have to* because people should be reasoning before they hit buttons, but in this day and age people don't really try to read between the lines anymore and close fast. A bit of a negative side effect of there being far too many low quality questions daily. Avoid terminology which makes one think it is asking for opinions, avoid terminology which makes it look like you're asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, etc. Those are two very common shoot from the hip lures.

Answer (score 12):

The way the question is worded ("why {feature}") and tagged ("language-design") strongly imply that the author is looking for the historical context why the particular decision was made for the given feature. Such questions often are hard to answer with facts and frequently end up with guesses as answers - hence gets closed as opinion-based to prevent such guess answers.

Based on the accepted answer the question was mostly about "what part of the language specification demands this behavior" (which can be answered with a quote(s) of the specification) - rewording the question to highlight that you are not interested in the history behind the decision would have likely prevented the closure. Additionally, if indeed the main goal of the question was exact specification explanation (vs. historical context) tagging with "language-lawyer" instead of "language-design" could clarify the goal.