# How can I improve this question? "Handle commits in `git rebase -i` in the opposite order"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, quality-improvement

The question is: [Handle commits in `git rebase -i` in the opposite order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78096800/handle-commits-in-git-rebase-i-in-the-opposite-order)

It currently has 3 downvotes, plus a close vote for being opinion-based. I think the question is pretty clear, but I'm biased, because I wrote it. What should I do?

Comment: :shrug: seems fine. just weird, as commenters have pointed out. Just because it has received downvotes doesn't mean there's anything you can change about it to reverse them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The close vote is bogus, and I wouldn't look deeper into it. While the idea of whether an opposite commit order would be more useful is indeed based on your opinion, the question is objectively asking how to obtain said list in reverse. If it gets closed for that reason, request it to be reopened.

There is still the risk of people not finding that approach useful, or there being no other solution but to develop a git intermediate command yourself (as already hinted by the comments), hence the downvotes. I don't think that there is much else one can do here, other than making it more focused on the end goal and less on the underlying opinion. For instance, you start with *"For reasons not entirely clear"*, which attracts the question for "why it was designed that way", something that is [often poorly received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio). The accepted answer in the linked question clarifies that the commits are in the order in which they will be applied, and that's just how it was implemented.

One other "rule" that often makes questions more well received is posing the title as an actual question. Feel free to work on top of my edit to your question.

Answer (score 11):

I personally don't see the point of what you're trying to do (I've never been troubled by the order of presentation of `git rebase -i` and personally wouldn't lift a finger to tweak it), but by itself that's not even a reason for a downvote, let alone a close vote. After all, many questions exist asking how to perform tasks that I simply have no interest in performing, and that's fine; it doesn't make them bad.

I think the question is fine; it's clear, narrow, answerable, and about a programming tool. My *only* nitpick is that I think that, taken on its own, the title (both originally and still after E_net4's edit) leaves it ambiguous if you're just looking for a presentational tweak or if you actually want Git to apply the newest ("least ancestral") commit *first* - i.e. to reverse the order of ancestry. I've tweaked the title in a way that I think eliminates this ambiguity, and thus makes the title basically serve as a self-contained and unambiguous statement of the question. Still, your intended meaning was already unambiguous from the question *body* and so I don't personally think it was ever deserving of a downvote.