Why is my question about library design choices opinion-based?
First, for reference, the question Why is the STL so heavily based on templates instead of inheritance? doesn't seem to have been deemed opinion-based. It asked about a design decision taken in the past, that influenced how the majority of the STL is written, i.e. using templates.
Recently I've asked what I think is a complementary question, Why do the IO library and the Diagnostic library make use of inheritance?, which pertains to the minority of the STL that is not based on templates, but which makes use of inheritance instead.
How in the world can one of the two questions be opinion-based and the other not be?

There seem to be at least two different questions in your question. The reason for IO library and diagnostic library can be very different (as you already noticed).

Not enough reviewers to catch all questions that should be closed I guess. That's why some questions that should be closed, aren't.

Also that first question is from 2009 when the rules were not as strict.

These early-day questions tend to make very poor benchmarks (especially when it comes to the question of what is an isn't on-topic).

because the consensus is that design choices are considered opinion based: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/

It's not opinion-based. Certainly not primarily so.
If you were asking, "Should I design my C++ library to use inheritance or templates?", then that would be the kind of thing we'd probably want to close as primarily opinion-based.
But you're not asking that. You're asking a fact-based question about why the existing C++ standard library was designed in a certain way. That can be objectively answered. Even if only by a small number of people.

While I agree with your judgment about being opinion based, the question still asks at least two different questions which will have different reasons (exceptions in diagnostics and streams in the IO library) and should be closed as Needs more focus. When you consider only the bold written part asking for an explanation about the IO library, then the self answer is NAA because it only talks about the diagnostics part.

Yes, I agree that the edits and the partial self-answer have made the question into a bit of a mess, which is completely independent of the "opinion-based" issue.

Ok, I've removed all of that. Can we reopen it now?

If you're asking about why a language/feature is designed the way it is, doesn't that still fall under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/?

@JimB Yes, this answer runs counter to Meta consensus and long-held site practice of closing such questions. However, it's posted by a moderator, so YMMV if you argue against it.

I believe Cody Gray is answering the question on his own perspective, and should not be regarded as an official ruling, nor as a consensus within the team of moderators. Still, it would have been better if this answer was extended onto the respective canonical question.

@JimB, your comment shows a very shallow understanding of the question I asked on SO, thought I might deduce from it that I can rephrase at least the title. I did not ask anybody to read in the thoughts of people that in the past designed that feature. I asked whether, given the purpose of the IO library, the language offers runtime polymorphism as the only possible way to eachive those goals. You can even look at my delete self-answer as to what a possible answer looks like, for what was the second half a double-question (nothing opinion based about it).

@Enlico JimB probably is looking at the question as it currently is phrased. It looks like the revision by cigien changed the meaning quite a bit.

@Enlico, I'm not claiming anything more than shallow knowledge of your original question, only pointing out that closing it generally follows accepted policy (which you may have self-confirmed by starting off with "Why is my question about library design choices...").

@JimB, apparently the "accepted policy" is allowed to be wrong. It happens anywhere, politics included. No wonder it happens here as well.

This answer is technically true, but that will not influence how people will vote. Which is... fast. Even if an OG is still around and active on Stack Overflow AND still knows why such ancient decisions were made, there is just no chance that they'll see it before the question is downvoted and closed. Because let's face it, the only way such questions are going to be received positively is when it gets answered as intended, by someone with actual knowledge. That will be the moment that people get starstruck enough to ignore the fact that the title reads like it is asking for opinions.

Eric Lippert (in that linked Q&A) is giving his opinion about these types of questions, not establishing a policy for whether or not they are allowed on Stack Overflow. He also goes on to provide some very practical advice about how to improve these types of questions, and given his significant expertise, anyone who wants to ask these types of questions and get good answers would be well-advised to follow. But, again, that answer doesn't establish that if you don't follow his suggestions your question is off-topic. (cc @JimB)

At the very top of Eric's answer, he even says that the problem with these questions is not that they're opinion-based, but that they're vague. So, if the question is vague and does not contain enough information to be answered, then it might be off-topic for Stack Overflow. But we have a close reason for that, and it's not the one labeled "primarily opinion-based".
